# Envío de imagen por api de whatsapp con php, desde servidor de google drive

Tags: php, imagen, google-drive, whatsapp

Tengo un problema al enviar imagenes de google drive a través de la api de whatsapp, con imágenes propias en servidor si funciona pero si envío el link de google drive no reconoce la imagen. El link de la imagen lo envío como parámetro a una Plantilla aprobada por la api de whatsapp.

Comment: Saludos, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código (en formato de texto) que estas utilizando. ;)

Comment: de seguro el error esta en el codigo o en la autenticacion en algunas de las api... pero creo que con los que has dicho y el codigo que has dado poco podemos hacer para reproducir el error y evaluar la posible solucion ...